# sum of big integer in varchar is different from varchar itselt

Tags: mysql, sum, varchar, bigint

Assume there is only one record:

| id | big_varchar |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1433549062949664079826 |

I find that the result is different for two queries:

- query 1: select sum(big_varchar) from tbl; // result = 1.433549062949664***2e21***
- query 2: select big_varchar from tbl;      // result = 1433549062949664***079826***

What should I do if I want the result using the exact number(i.e. 1433549062949664079826) when doing SUM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use SUM() then the column datatype is converted implicitly, and DOUBLE datatype is used. So use explicit convertion.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tbl SELECT 1 id, '1433549062949664079826' big_varchar;
> select sum(big_varchar) from tbl;
> select big_varchar from tbl;
> select sum(CAST(big_varchar AS UNSIGNED)) from tbl;
> select CAST(big_varchar AS UNSIGNED) from tbl;
> select sum(CAST(big_varchar AS DECIMAL(32))) from tbl;
> select CAST(big_varchar AS DECIMAL(32)) from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> |      sum(big_varchar) |
> | --------------------: |
> | 1.4335490629496642e21 |
>
> | big_varchar            |
> | :--------------------- |
> | 1433549062949664079826 |
>
> | sum(CAST(big_varchar AS UNSIGNED)) |
> | ---------------------------------: |
> |               18446744073709551615 |
>
> | CAST(big_varchar AS UNSIGNED) |
> | ----------------------------: |
> |          18446744073709551615 |
>
> | sum(CAST(big_varchar AS DECIMAL(32))) |
> | ------------------------------------: |
> |                1433549062949664079826 |
>
> | CAST(big_varchar AS DECIMAL(32)) |
> | -------------------------------: |
> |           1433549062949664079826 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1fb4c3742b7c0dee5dec1285a928ca43)*

Comment: 18446744073709551615 is different from the original value 1433549062949664079826

Comment: @YipHonWaiEthan Updated. The datatype which provides correct output id DECIMAL.